# Maperitive: how to add a new rule-set

Tags: openstreetmap, maperitive

Maperitive, a desktop OSM renderer, stores its rulesets for rendering in a subfolder called "Rules" - at least when running under Windows.

I tried to generate my own rules (or to be more honest I changed a ruleset) and saved it under a new name like "myruleset.mrules" in this folder. Unfortunately, Maperitive does not seem to "recognize" new files in this subfolder "Rules". Restarting Maperitive does not help.

How can I "register" this new ruleset, so that it is available under the menu Map -> Switch to Rules?

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I figured it out. On the command-prompt, run:

```
use-ruleset location=rules\myruleset.mrules
```

Maperitive will add this ruleset under Map->Switch to Rules

Comment: That's correct. There's no special folder for rules, you can load them from anywhere. You can also simply drag&drop the rules file into Maperitive.

Comment: Igor Brejc pointed me to this intro page for working with rule files: http://maperitive.net/docs/Rulesets.html#Removing%20Rulesets there you find also the command  remove-ruleset, which works (although the page says todo) very well in version 2.3.14 of maperitive